# conditional list selection and appending of variable in R

Tags: list, r

Say i have a list mn like this

```
i<-c(w=5,n="oes")
p<-c(w=9,n="ty",j="ooe")
mn<-list(i,p,i,p,i,p,i)
```

Now I´d like to select the list elements with the shortest length (the i´s) and append "unknown" to the list before creating a dataframe. How can I do this?

EDIT: In the end I´d like the list to have every i element in mn as w=5,n="oes", and j="unknown" before mn including p is changed into a dataframe:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the lenght of each element in your list, use `length` wrapped in `sapply`:

```
len <- sapply(mn, length)
len
[1] 2 3 2 3 2 3 2
```

Now, to identify only those elements that have lengths equal to the shortest length:

```
which(len==min(len))
[1] 1 3 5 7
```

Use subsetting and `as.data.frame` to create your data.frame.  But this data.frame will have somewhat random column names, so I rename the column names:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mn[which(len==min(len))])
names(df) <- seq_len(ncol(df))
df
    1   2   3   4
w   5   5   5   5
n oes oes oes oes
```

You will have to clarify what you mean with "append unknown" to this data.frame.

Comment: `which.min(len)` will be more efficient than `which(len==min(len))`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not very elegant, but it might do the trick:

```
maxlength <- max(sapply(mn,length))
## make a new list, with the "missing" entries replaced with "unknown"
mn2 <- lapply(mn,function(x)c(x,rep('unknown',maxlength - length(x))))
## convert to a data.frame
mn3 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(mn2),nrow = 3))
```

Which gives the following

```
> mn3
       X1  X2      X3  X4      X5  X6      X7
1       5   9       5   9       5   9       5
2     oes  ty     oes  ty     oes  ty     oes
3 unknown ooe unknown ooe unknown ooe unknown
```

However it is better practice to use `NA`, rather than `"unknown"`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:

```
all.names = unique( unlist( lapply( mn, names ) ) )
do.call( 'rbind', lapply( mn, function( r ) {
  data.frame( sapply( all.names, function( v ) r[ v ], simplify=F ) )
} ) )
```

which gives:

```
   w   n    j
w  5 oes <NA>
w1 9  ty  ooe
w2 5 oes <NA>
w3 9  ty  ooe
w4 5 oes <NA>
w5 9  ty  ooe
w6 5 oes <NA>
```

But I get the feeling there's a much neater route to this solution...

**edit**

If you want `unknown` rather than `<NA>`, you can change the inner `sapply` to:

```
sapply( all.names, function( v ) if( is.na( r[v] ) ) 'unknown' else r[v], simplify=F )
```